# Opposite of broadcast

Tags: java, stream, akka, akka-stream

I can create a Source, that has integers {1, 2, 3} and using Broadcast it will create me N Sources, and each will have {1, 2, 3}.

I want to do opposite, I have N Sources and each should provide exactly same integers {1, 2, 3} and using ??? I want to create single Source, that will have {1, 2, 3}.

I will call my operation ??? as "implode" as I do not have better name.

To answer obvious question that comes to Your mind: "why to do this weird thing and not just take any of those Sources" I have to note, that those N Sources are *expected* to provide same data, but in practice some may not respond at all. What if they will respond with different data? This is error that violates our business logic, so throwing Exception is ok.

Example:
I have two Sources (A and B) of Integers, and both have {1, 2, 3}. Now I ask both of them at same time for Integer. Source B responds faster than A with Integer 1, so I as imploded Source respond with 1 immediately (without even waiting for answer from Source A).

Now I ask both Sources for next element, and this time A responds faster with 2 (I am ignoring it's 1) and I am returning 2 without waiting for B.

Now I ask both Sources for next element, and A throws ConnectionLostBecauseReasonsException however B responds with 3 so imploded Source returns 3 and everything is ok.

So here advantage is speed - my imploded Source is as fast as fastest Sources that I aggregate plus it shields me from exceptions from N-1 Sources.

In the end, I am trying to implement function like:

```
<T> Source<T, ?> implode(List<Source<T, ?>> sources);
```

The closest I got was using Zip - wait for results from all N Sources, and then (by using my function) return any of them. It does shield me from exceptions, however makes me as fast as slowest one, and this isn't what I want.

Is there already implemented strategy like mine "implode"? If yes, what is it's name? If no, how should I implement it myself?

Here is what I have tried:

```
class Multi
{   
    static <T> Source<T, ?> merger(List<Source<T, ?>> sources)
    {
        switch(sources.size())
        {
            case 0: throw new RuntimeException("No sources provided!");
            case 1: return sources.get(0);
            default: return Source.zipWithN(Multi::zip, sources);
        }
    }

    private static <T> T zip(List<T> list)
    {
        return list
            .stream()
            .reduce(Multi::same)
            .orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
    }

    private static <T> T same(T first, T second)
    {
        if(Objects.equals(first, second))
        {
            return first;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Source<Integer, ?> source1 = Source.from(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
        Source<Integer, ?> source2 = Source.from(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
        Source<Integer, ?> merger = merger(Arrays.asList(source1, source2));

        merger
            .runForeach(System.out::println, ActorMaterializer.create(ActorSystem.create()))
            .thenRun(() -> System.out.println("done"));
    }
}
```

This code outputs: 1 2 3 done

and I would like: 1 2 3 4 done

however, my zip method is called only three times, so I don't get chance to do so. Second problem is that I wait for all sources, instead of returning value as fast as I can. It covers my case of throwing exception when values are different, therefore

```
Source<Integer, ?> source1 = Source.from(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 4));
Source<Integer, ?> source2 = Source.from(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
```

outputs: 1 2 exception

as expected.

Comment: Opposite of broadcast is emit

Comment: I can't find class/method named "emit" in Akka, so I guess You are referring to naming convention rather than solution?

Comment: Merge: http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/akka/stream/scaladsl/Merge$.html

Comment: would You be so kind and provide minimal example?